# Auth Error Cascading MapBox WMTS with GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, mapbox, wmts, authentication, getcapabilities

I'm trying to cascade MapBox WMTS with Geoserver using the following GetCapabilities url:

```
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/dark-v10/wmts?access_token=pk.
```

But Geoserver is getting a 401 `{"message":"Not Authorized - No Token"}` response from MapBox:

```
WMTS Connection test failed: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/dark-v10/wmts?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.0.0&ACCESS_TOKEN=pk.
```

It seems that `access_token` is case sensitive as I get a 200 response when using curl:

```
curl "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/dark-v10/wmts?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.0.0&access_token=pk" 

StatusCode: 200
```

Is there a workaround to prevent Geoserver from capitalizing the request parameters, or perhaps manually creating the store?

I see the 'Key Authentication' module does something similar for incoming requests.

Comment: To access Mapboc API, you need access token, see https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/access-tokens/. What you have specified as access token are just first three standard characters of public scope token.

Comment: Check the GeoServer logs with debug turned up to see the actual url being sent

Comment: I get the same response when testing with curl for both upper and lower case.

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this with the same issue... a bug report is open for this issue - https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-8388

Answer (score 1):

This was indeed a [bug](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/GEOT/issues/GEOT-6677) in how GeoServer handles parameters in cascaded requests, though a well built service should not care about the case of it's parameters so you may want to raise an issue with MapBox.

This has been [fixed](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/pull/3492) in the latest master version of GeoTools (26.x) and will be in the next release of GeoServer (2.20.0). We welcome backports if you need it in an earlier release.

Answer (score 0):

My experiments seem to suggest that the issue could be because of GeoServer capitalizing the query parameters names, as you suggested.

A workaround may be to proxy all Mapbox requests so you can reverse the capitalization applied on the proxied onwards requests.

I also encounter the same issue when trying to consume the LINZ Basemaps service, resulting in a 400 error - https://basemaps.linz.govt.nz/